# How to find the target planet of a previous mission in the galaxy?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have solved a mission and want to return to the planet from a previous mission. After selecting this previous mission in <kbd>P</kbd> I can see my actual ship position in the galaxy. But I'm not able to see the mission target on my HUD and therefore I cannot choose a target and make a "hyper jump" to this location.

How can I set a waypoint in the Galaxy Map to the target planet?
Or how can I navigate to the planet I got this previous mission?

Comment: Is the mission your current objective?  In the log, mark it as the active one.  I *think* that will place its marker.

Comment: Did you visit the space station of that system? Then you can simply teleport there.

Comment: Just left the "Anomaly" sphere the first time. "Polo" ordered me to come back in 2 hours and solve some other missions in the meantime. Now I'm flying in front of the sphere in the galaxy and can't find the planet with the previous quest giver. I just see that it "is in another system". But where? And I get there?

Comment: The teleportation system is always offline for me. Whatever I try to build on the surface of a planet, I can't teleport to the space station and from the space station I can't get back to the my base. I'm not sure if I have to do some more warp jumps or if I miss something else (other then the stargate-like teleporter).

Comment: @PeterCo You can jump from space station to space station. Just go to one space station, from there you can teleport to every other space station you have visited.

Comment: After a dinner break I restarted NMS and visited a base on a nearby planet. There I UPLOADED my base (*strange*) and some seconds later my teleportation stargate finally worked! A target list was presented, including the one with the missing quest giver. (I'm not sure if it this was a game-restart-thing or the upload of the base.) After my teleportation my space ship was waiting for me in the hangar, surprisingly it was teleported (automatically) too.

Comment: @PeterCo Yes, starships are always teleported with you. If you are missing your starship, you can summon it with the "X" menu. Same as your freighter.